# How to do Date parsing and formating inside a bindview of cursor adapter in android

Tags: java, android, sqlite, simpledateformat, android-cursorloader

I have saved my dates in my sqlite table like **2016-04-20** and I want my listview display them as **20/4/2016** and I use the following inside the bindview of a cursor adapter

```
String InitialDate=cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(cursor.getColumnName(2)));

SimpleDateFormat curFormater = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd");
Date dateObj = curFormater.parse(InitialDate);
SimpleDateFormat postFormater = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy");
String newDateStr = postFormater.format(dateObj);
textViewDate.setText(newDateStr);
```

but before I do anything the part of parse says Unhandled Exception java.text.ParseException I have import of

```
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
import java.util.Date;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you should use try/catch block for `parse` method call because it can produce [checked exception](https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Java_Programming/Checked_Exceptions):

```
Date dateObj = null;
try {
    dateObj = curFormater.parse(InitialDate);
} catch (ParseException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

or you can just rethrow this exception from your method (you should use `throws ParseException` clause in method signature)

via [documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/exceptions/catchOrDeclare.html):

> Checked exceptions are subject to the Catch or Specify Requirement. All exceptions are checked exceptions, except for those indicated by Error, RuntimeException, and their subclasses.

Answer (score 1):

These is because the method you are calling **can** throw an exception and you are not taking care of it.. look:

```
Date java.text.DateFormat.parse(String source) throws ParseException
```

> Throws:   ParseException - if the beginning of the specified string
>   cannot be parsed.

This basically means, if you try to convert a non-sense into a date, the `java.text.DateFormat` class will try its best to but if not possible will throw the exception, that you must either catch using the properly try-catch statement or just re throwing the exception so others can take care of it..

## So at the end your options are:

1. Re throw the exception

t

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws ParseException {
    String InitialDate = new String("2016-04-20");
    SimpleDateFormat curFormater = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd");
    Date dateObj = curFormater.parse(InitialDate);
    SimpleDateFormat postFormater = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy");
    String newDateStr = postFormater.format(dateObj);
}
```

2. Use the properly try catch

Use....

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    String InitialDate = new String("2016-04-20");
    SimpleDateFormat curFormater = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd");
    Date dateObj;
    try {
        dateObj = curFormater.parse(InitialDate);
        SimpleDateFormat postFormater = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy");
        String newDateStr = postFormater.format(dateObj);
    } catch (ParseException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        System.err.println("a non sense was here");
    }
}
```